# Ajax call doesnot work when submit button is used

Tags: php, ajax

Below is the simple code to call the ajax but when I click submit button,it doesn't work. I did echo "hello world"; in second file "test.php". Can someone get me out of this?

```
<html>
        <head>
        <title>AJAX TUTORIAL</title>
        <script src= "jqueryy.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sub").click(function(){
        //var user_email=$("#email").val();
        $.post("test.php",function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
        });
        });
        });
        </script>
        </head>
            <body>
            <div id="box">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
            <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Submit"/>
            <div id="result">

            </div>
            </div>

            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: and your jquery file name is correct jqueryy.js  at end double yy ? @Luqman

Comment: you need to include the jquery

Comment: did you have any error in console

Comment: yes the file name is jqueryy.js and there is no error in the console

Comment: first check click function is working or not like this $("#sub").click(function(){
  alert("hi");
        });  comment all other lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any form tag .so it will not reload the page when submit is clicked 
 I think your code seems good .

1) May be the problem is jquery included file name typo error `jqueryy.js`  at the end double yy .

or

2) remove that link and replace with this cdn link and try

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question already states the answer, `Ajax call doesnot work when submit button is used`. Because `submit` button submit the form to the server and it reloads the page, that's why your ajax do not initiates.

So you have to `hold the form submission` or change button from `submit` to `button`.

But there is no `form` in your code. And you are including jquery like:

```
<script src= "jqueryy.js"></script>
```

please check if there is a js file with the name `jqueryy.js` present in the specified path.

Comment: but he don't have any form tag .so it will not reload the page when submit is clicked

Comment: I have changed input type from submit to button but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the from from submitting by either waiting on the submit event for the form, or click listener for the button

For the button:

```
$('#sub').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Your code here
});
```

For the form:

1: Wrap your inputs in a  tag

2: This code bit

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Your Code here
})
```

On both of these, you have the e.preventDefault(); In short, it prevents the default action of your selector. In this case the form submission.

Comment: there is no form so no need to prevent the form submit